# Visual Studio 2022 WSL unit tests as root

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

How do I run Visual Studio 2022 unit tests to WSL as root?

I have a testEnvironments.json file that is able to run unit tests to my WSL instance from Visual Studio 2022 on Windows 11. Unfortunately there seems to be no way to force these tests to run as sudo / root. I've already tried running Visual Studio as administrator.

I have verified the `getuid` returns a non-zero value.

I have a hard requirement of running my code as root on Linux.

```cs
{
  "version": "1",
  "environments":
  [
    {
      "name": "Ubuntu",
      "type": "wsl",
      "wslDistribution": "Ubuntu"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run from powershell:

```
ubuntu config --default-user root
```

If that does not work, try using the following code for the testEnvironments.json file:

```
{
  "version": "1",
  "environments":
  [
    {
      "name": "Ubuntu",
      "type": "wsl",
      "wslDistribution": "Ubuntu",
      "runAsRoot": "true"
    }
  ]
}
```

If not, I suggest you refer to these two documents.[1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/basic-commands#run-a-specific-linux-distribution-from-powershell-or-cmd) [2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/troubleshooting#using-older-versions-of-windows-and-wsl)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is there a link to the runAsRoot in documentation somewhere? Did not see it on either link.

Comment: This unfortunately did not work, the dotnet processes on the wsl instance are still spun up as the regular user with id 1000

Comment: Running `ubuntu config --default-user root` from powershell solved the problem.